# Fitting the Debye temperature of a magnetic material from heat capacity

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

Because of the magnon contribution, the low-temperature range (eg. 1.8~10 K) cannot purely be divided into electron term $\gamma$ and phonon term. Thus I cannot simply use the $C_p/T \sim T^2$ relation to extract the Debye temperature.

On the other hand, fitting of the complete Debye formula from above the magnetic transition temperature, say $T_N = 200$ K, usually gives me a large uncertainty since the curve is almost flattened above that temperature.

How could I get an accurate Debye temperature from the heat capacity of a magnetic material?